# Where is csharp-sqlite now maintained?

Tags: forking, collaboration

csharp-sqlite is the only pure-C# implementation of an SQLite client.

The project used to live at https://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite
The last update was 4 years ago.

The homepage says:

> For preparing to google code will be disconnected at August. csharp-sqlite will be moved (exported) to GitHub. Later information will be posted here soon.

[Many people have exported it to Github](https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=csharp-sqlite) but none seems to be maintaining it.

It has been months since this notice got posted, it seems like the maintainer has "[moved on to other interests](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/csharp-sqlite/hMhtJJcyYs0)".

Is csharp-sqlite maintained somewhere? Are there active forks (maybe renamed) that I haven't found?

Comment: Discussion about whether this question is on-topic or off-topic: http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/269/where-is-old-arcane-project-now-maintained-maybe-as-a-fork-under-another-name

Comment: In this case, is there an effective difference between https://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/ and https://code.google.com/p/sqlite-net/ ?

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: It can be very confusing, but they are indeed different projects. From sqlite-net's website: "*This is not a full SQLite driver. If you need that, go get System.Data.SQLite or csharp-sqlite*".

Comment: A possible related question that comes to mind: "I have found something that claims to be $foobar source code, that was abandoned years ago. can I tell that this is actually the $foobar source code?". Might be challenging to keep this one on-topic, but is maybe worth a try - and may be relevant if major hosters shut down and remove code that "just used to be there".

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher: Sounds like an interesting question actually! Don't hesitate to ask about it on Meta. Could be more generally about "genealogy" of the source code of particular open source projects.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a csharp-sqlite support question, not a question relevant to people who participate in open source projects. See [this meta thread](https://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/150/are-questions-about-specific-software-on-topic).

Comment: @Gilles: a) the link gives a HTTP 403 for me. b) What if I want to participate in the development of csharp-sqlite and can't identify the "real" project?

Comment: @Gilles: That has been discussed already, and the result is clearly: on-topic http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/269/where-is-old-arcane-project-now-maintained-maybe-as-a-fork-under-another-name Also, the meta question you linked to is totally unrelated, it is about programming questions ("*I couldn't understand what function ABC() does*"), not about governance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer: **No.**

This product has been discontinued by the developer. It is up to the developer to do what he/she said they would do. It is quite possible they lost interest in the project and have moved on to other projects.

No activity could just mean they have not got around to it.

Advice: stay patient, if you really need to know you could contact the developer.